# ImportError: cannot import name 'solve_ivp'

Tags: python, scipy

I don't understand why I have this error... Here is the code :

```
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
def exponential_decay(t, y): return -0.5 * y
sol = solve_ivp(exponential_decay, [0, 10], [2, 4, 8])
print(sol.t)
```

I'm using python 3.2.8

Comment: What version of `scipy` do you have?

Comment: Please post the error

Comment: @DanielLee The error is the title of the question. Added scipy tag to better index the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that [`scipy.integrate.solve_ivp()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html#scipy.integrate.solve_ivp) was only introduced in `scipy` versions > 0.19.1:

Documentation for [version 0.19.1](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/integrate.html#module-scipy.integrate) and documentation for [version 1.0.0](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.0.0/reference/integrate.html#module-scipy.integrate).

In order to use that function you will have to upgrade your version of `scipy`

Comment: Thanks you a lot!

Comment: I upgraded it and i still cannot use it :                                                                
      4 from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
      5 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      6 import os

ImportError: cannot import name 'solve_ivp'